# How to add a color bar for vspans created with variable alpha

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I would like to use varying degrees of red color to represent the different importance of each time element and fill in that region.

The example code is shown below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X_example = np.random.rand(400)
importance_values = np.random.rand(400)
plt.figure(figsize=(13,7))
plt.plot(X_example)
for j in range(len(X_example)):
    plt.axvspan(xmin=j, xmax=j+1,facecolor="r",alpha=importance_values[j])
```

It generates a graph like:

[image: generated graph]

Now I would like to add a colormap in this figure to show that, e.g. the light red means low importance and the dark red means high importance, just like this:

[image: desired colormap]

How could I achieve that in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a colormap mixing the red color with a range of alpha values:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, to_rgba
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import numpy as np

X_example = np.random.rand(400)
importance_values = np.random.rand(400)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
ax.plot(X_example)
for j in range(len(X_example)):
    ax.axvspan(xmin=j, xmax=j + 1, facecolor="r", alpha=importance_values[j])
ax.margins(x=0)

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(None, [to_rgba('r', 0), 'r'])
cbar = plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap), ticks=[0, 1], pad=0.02)
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(["low", "high"], fontsize=20)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel("importance", labelpad=-30, fontsize=20)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: colorbar containing range of alpha values]

An example of a horizontal colorbar:

```py
cbar = plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap), ticks=[0, 1], orientation='horizontal')
cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(["low", "high"], fontsize=20)
cbar.ax.set_xlabel("importance", labelpad=-15, fontsize=20)
```

[image: horizontal colorbar]

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create a `LinearSegmentedColormap` which takes a list of colors and turns it into a matplotlib colorbar object. Then you can set the "alpha channel":

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, ListedColormap
from matplotlib.colorbar import ColorbarBase

X_example = np.random.rand(400)
importance_values = np.random.rand(400)

fig, (ax, cax) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(8,5), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [1, 0.05]})
ax.plot(X_example, color='b')
for j in range(len(X_example)):
    ax.axvspan(xmin=j, xmax=j+1,facecolor="r",alpha=importance_values[j])
    
N = 20  # the number of colors/alpha-values in the colorbar
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(None, ['r' for i in range(N)], N=N)
alpha_cmap = cmap(np.arange(N))
alpha_cmap[:,-1] = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
alpha_cmap = ListedColormap(alpha_cmap, N=N)

cbar = ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=alpha_cmap, ticks=[0., 1],)
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(["low importance", "high importance"])
```

This gives the following plot, where the two colors of the colorbar have custom labels:

[image]

Comment: Many thx for your help! This is really helpful and solved my problem!